# PHP Contact Form returning error upon submission

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts

So I've tried publishing a page with PHP contact form on 2 different servers and I can't get either of them to work perfectly.

Server 1:
Returns a `500 internal error` page upon submission.
I contacted web support and they replied saying I have a:

> malformed header from script 'index.php': Bad header:

My code for index.php as follows:

```
    <?php
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
 {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $query = $_POST['message'];
    $email_from = $name.'<'.$email.'>';

 $to="testemail@email.com";
 $subject="test subject";
 $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
 $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
 $headers .= "From: ".$email_from."\r\n";
 $message="   

         Name:
         $name     
         <br>
         Email:
         $email        
         <br>
         Message:
         $query        

   ";
    if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
        header("Location:../contact.php?msg=Successful Submission!<br />
 Thank you for contacting us.");
    else
        header("Location:../contact.php?msg=Error To send Email !");
 }
?>
```

Server 2:
Links me to my "Thank you page" correctly, but it's showing 
"Error To send Email !" instead of 
"Successful Submission!"

Any help or advice will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Aside what was noted in below answers (1. Use an absolute URI in `header("Location: ...);` and 2. `urlencode()` your query string), if you intend to send out headers, you'll want to trim that leading space before your PHP opening tag.

Comment: In addition to the answers make sure the code you presented above appear topmost on your page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the propblem is in this part:

```
 if(mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers))
        header("Location:../contact.php?msg=Successful Submission!<br />
 Thank you for contacting us.");
    else
        header("Location:../contact.php?msg=Error To send Email !");
```

Specificly in the `header();`

1. each space would be converted to %20 as there are no URLs with spaces;
2. There are no special characters like <, >, ! in URLs
3. The "/" in `<br />` would suggest a file called ">Thank you for contacting us."

Check out: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp;

Also put `exit();` after each header to prevent futher execution of the script

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be the header location redirect call which should provide a full url, e.g.:

```
header("Location: http://www.example.com");
```

Relative urls are processed as per the browser's best efforts and your browser clearly isn't liking the ../, hence the "bad header" complaint.

This is noted on the [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#refsect1-function.header-notes) page as per the [official URL spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30).